# Does the Windows-folder contain personal files?

Tags: windows, backup

I'm currently going through hard drives of my previous computers (Win 98 through Win 7). The goal is to identify personal files, communication, or programs to keep before I throw away the drives. Unfortunately, I wasn't very organized with files on my early computers.

I'm going through the old file systems folder-by-folders. Files to keep are usually in the `Desktop` folder, the `AppData` folder, the `Program Files` folder etc.

My question: Is there any sub folder of the `Windows` folder I should be looking at? Or is it all generic Windows drivers and I can ignore the `Windows` folder entirely?

Comment: Technically it depends on the software and what you class as personal files really

Answer (score 2):

Windows 9x kept user profiles in subdirectories of the `Profiles` directory in the Windows installation directory. So that is definitely one place you do want to look in.

`My Documents` would be a given, but I think you already have that covered. As I recall it'll be either under a profile directory or directly in the root of the system drive.

Also, `.ini` files were sometimes stored in the Windows installation directory. Most of these should be system-global, of little relevance today, and .ini files were generally deprecated with the advent of Windows 95 in favor of using the registry, but it's still something you might want to look out for.

You should, however, be able to safely ignore the `System` directory and anything under it. (I don't think Windows 9x ever had `System32`; that was a Windows NT construct.) There are a *few* exceptions, like perhaps \windows\system\hosts (as I believe was the name of the equivalent to \windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts today) but if you haven't needed it for several years, chances are it's out of date anyway.

Comment: I recall Windows 98 has system32 in it https://youtu.be/2WlkZZuMLeM because [system is the folder for 16-bit Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder#File_system_directories)